# scraping data from table on website using xpath

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, rvest

I'm trying to get data from the table with all the colors from the following website: https://azdeq.gov/aq/ytd?year=2022&pollutant=pm25&location=pinal&type=conc#mtop

Here's what I've done.

1. Inspected element & found table
2. Copied table's XPath: //*[@id="node-5748"]/div/div/div/div/div[5]
3. Spent way more time on this simple bit of code than I was hoping
4. Table is empty...same results using css & selector
5. I've used other methods to get access to some of the data, but the blanks are not showing up and throwing things off.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
library(rvest)

# Scrape the table from the website
table <- read_html("https://azdeq.gov/aq/ytd?year=2022&pollutant=pm25&location=pinal&type=conc#mtop") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="node-5748"]/div/div/div/div/div[5]') %>%
  html_table()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the data isn't stored in an actual HTML table. It's stored in a bunch of div tags so it seems the `html_table()` can't parse that data. You could do a bit of your own processing. For example

```
library(rvest)
page <-read_html("https://azdeq.gov/aq/ytd?year=2022&pollutant=pm25&location=pinal&type=conc#mtop")
block <- html_nodes(page, "div.divPollYTD") %>% `[[`(2)

lapply(block %>% html_elements(".divPollRowYTD"), function(row)
  row %>% html_elements("div") %>% html_text()
) |> 
  do.call("rbind", args=_)
#       [,1]  [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10]  [,11]  [,12]  [,13] 
#  [1,] "Day" "Jan"  "Feb"  "Mar"  "Apr"  "May"  "Jun"  "Jul"  "Aug"  "Sep"  "Oct"  "Nov"  "Dec" 
#  [2,] "1"   "7.1"  "11.2" "6.9"  "5.7"  "13"   "20.3" "8.7"  "3.4"  "13.2" "3"    "8.4"  "7"   
#  [3,] "2"   "6.5"  "10.3" "15.1" "5.6"  "14.7" "18.9" "13.2" "3.7"  "15.2" "4.9"  "13.5" "8.2" 
#  [4,] "3"   "6.2"  "11"   "10.9" "5.3"  "12.4" "14.7" "7.6"  "5.1"  "3.5"  "57.8" "7.7"  "7.1" 
#  [5,] "4"   "8.3"  "11.7" "6.7"  "6.7"  "7.4"  "11.2" "10.5" "2.2"  "10.5" "4.9"  "6.9"  "3.7" 
#  [6,] "5"   "13.6" "7.1"  "9.4"  "6.8"  "16"   "8.9"  "7.2"  "4"    "19.5" "6.6"  "9.5"  "3.4" 
#   etc...
```

This returns a character array but you could coerce that to a data.frame or whatever else you like.